# Define function of list of integers such that their sum is n

Tags: haskell, recursion, combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following problem with Haskell:

**Problem**

Define the function `sumToLists :: Int -> [[Int]]` that, given a natural number `n`, it returns all the lists of positive numbers such that their sum is `n`.

I am pretty lost at this problem, maybe using recursion could yield up a solution but I have no clue how to attack this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I thought of something of the form [ (n-i):sumToLists i] | i <-[1...n-1] ] but I am not sure if I can apply ":" to add the head element n-i inside a list by comprehension. This is the only thing I came up with so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
sumToLists 0 = [[]]
sumToLists n = [ i: xs | i <- [1..n], xs <- sumToLists (n - i) ]
```

you need special case for `0` because default will return `[]` not `[[]]`.